# Why am I able to use isspace() without including the required header?

Tags: c

Why does this code work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x = isspace(getchar());
        printf("%d", x);
        return 0;
    }
```

Whenever I enter whitespace `isspace()` returns 8 and when I don't, it gives 0.

Shouldn't this produce an error at compile time? I didn't add `#include <ctype.h>` at the top. So why this is allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing this because your compiler (*sadly, still*) supports implicit declaration of a function.

If you enable strict checking, you compiler should refuse to compile the code. On and above `C99`, the implicit function declaration has been made non-standard. (*To add, hopefully, future versions of compiler will strictly disallow this, by default.*)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a specific implementation of the C Standard Libraries will support one header by including another itself: in your case, stdio.h may be including - either directly or indirectly - the `isspace` declaration, which might itself be directly in `ctype.h` or in some other file that `ctype.h` would include.  You could test for this by executing just your preprocessing stage, as in...

```
gcc -E myprog.c | grep isspace
```

Another thing that can happen is that compilers hardcode implementations of common functions, like say `strlen`, so they can e.g. perform it at compile time on string literals.

Despite it "working", you would ideally directly include the headers you'll need, so if another compiler/implementation - or a later release of the same - doesn't have the same quirks your code will still compile.